# Displaying JavaScript generated QR code without HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have tested the following to generate and display a QR code and its working fine on my desktop.

The library I use is [qrcode.js](https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/blob/master/qrcode.js)

```
<head>
  <title>Cross-Browser QRCode generator for Javascript</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="qrcode.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="qrcode" style="width:100px; height:100px; margin-top:15px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    });

    qrcode.makeCode("Hello World");
  </script>
</body>
```

The issue is I want to run this code on an embedded device which restricts the use of JavaScript:

> ...all JS code is preprocessed before executing the HTML code. Thus in JS one cannot get or read any of the html elements. This may limit the use third party JS library components which typically allow getting access to the HTML DOM element and then perform operations which is not allowed in our case.

Is it possible to display this QR in HTML without the use of `getElementById`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a good first question! A couple of notes, though: 1. It's important to show the `QRCode` implementation or at least tell us what specific library you're using. 2. Code *snippets* (the `[<>]` button you clicked) are for **runnable** examples. Since yours wasn't runnable, you wanted just a code block (the `{}` button). 3. Use `>` at the beginning of the line to quote something. (I've made the changes for #2 and #3 for you, but you still need to handle #1.)

Comment: You just need to run that piece of code after the page has loaded.  That would normally happen in the "onload" event for the body.

Answer (score 0):

Not with this library I guess.. This library requires a dom element to append too.

Possible solution is generating and qr-image. Then open the image?
And another solution is converting the returned SVG to base64, and open the url. But this requires rewriting the qrcode.js file.

Comment: saving the image and opening it later was my first thought but that will require editing the library too right?

Comment: Yes, the library returns an svg by default (what it looks like). You need to return the base64 url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `jsdom` and this code to render it server side using node.js, if that's a possibility. (Yes node.js can run on some embedded devices too... if that is your server for some reason)

https://repl.it/@CodyGeisler/RenderQRCodeServerSide

```js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

// Creates a virtual DOM!
const { document, navigator } = (new JSDOM(`<html><div id="qrcode"></div></html>`)).window;

// THIS IS THE CODE FROM https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/blob/master/qrcode.min.js
// Side note: you should never run code you don't trust.
var QRCode;!function(){function a(a){this.mode=c.MODE_8BIT_BYTE,this.data=a,this.parsedData=[];for(var b=[],d=0,e=this.data.length;e>d;d++){var f=this.data.charCodeAt(d);f>65536?(b[0]=240|(1835008&f)>>>18,b[1]=128|(258048&f)>>>12,b[2]=128|(4032&f)>>>6,b[3]=128|63&f):f>2048?(b[0]=224|(61440&f)>>>12,b[1]=128|(4032&f)>>>6,b[2]=128|63&f):f>128?(b[0]=192|(1984&f)>>>6,b[1]=128|63&f):b[0]=f,this.parsedData=this.parsedData.concat(b)}this.parsedData.length!=this.data.length&&(this.parsedData.unshift(191),this.parsedData.unshift(187),this.parsedData.unshift(239))}function b(a,b){this.typeNumber=a,this.errorCorrectLevel=b,this.modules=null,this.moduleCount=0,this.dataCache=null,this.dataList=[]}function i(a,b){if(void 0==a.length)throw new Error(a.length+"/"+b);for(var c=0;c<a.length&&0==a[c];)c++;this.num=new Array(a.length-c+b);for(var d=0;d<a.length-c;d++)this.num[d]=a[d+c]}function j(a,b){this.totalCount=a,this.dataCount=b}function k(){this.buffer=[],this.length=0}function m(){return"undefined"!=typeof CanvasRenderingContext2D}function n(){var a=!1,b=navigator.userAgent;return/android/i.test(b)&&(a=!0,aMat=b.toString().match(/android ([0-9]\.[0-9])/i),aMat&&aMat[1]&&(a=parseFloat(aMat[1]))),a}function r(a,b){for(var c=1,e=s(a),f=0,g=l.length;g>=f;f++){var h=0;switch(b){case d.L:h=l[f][0];break;case d.M:h=l[f][1];break;case d.Q:h=l[f][2];break;case d.H:h=l[f][3]}if(h>=e)break;c++}if(c>l.length)throw new Error("Too long data");return c}function s(a){var b=encodeURI(a).toString().replace(/\%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/g,"a");return b.length+(b.length!=a?3:0)}a.prototype={getLength:function(){return this.parsedData.length},write:function(a){for(var b=0,c=this.parsedData.length;c>b;b++)a.put(this.parsedData[b],8)}},b.prototype={addData:function(b){var c=new a(b);this.dataList.push(c),this.dataCache=null},isDark:function(a,b){if(0>a||this.moduleCount<=a||0>b||this.moduleCount<=b)throw new Error(a+","+b);return this.modules[a][b]},getModuleCount:function(){return this.moduleCount},make:function(){this.makeImpl(!1,this.getBestMaskPattern())},makeImpl:function(a,c){this.moduleCount=4*this.typeNumber+17,this.modules=new Array(this.moduleCount);for(var d=0;d<this.moduleCount;d++){this.modules[d]=new Array(this.moduleCount);for(var e=0;e<this.moduleCount;e++)this.modules[d][e]=null}this.setupPositionProbePattern(0,0),this.setupPositionProbePattern(this.moduleCount-7,0),this.setupPositionProbePattern(0,this.moduleCount-7),this.setupPositionAdjustPattern(),this.setupTimingPattern(),this.setupTypeInfo(a,c),this.typeNumber>=7&&this.setupTypeNumber(a),null==this.dataCache&&(this.dataCache=b.createData(this.typeNumber,this.errorCorrectLevel,this.dataList)),this.mapData(this.dataCache,c)},setupPositionProbePattern:function(a,b){for(var c=-1;7>=c;c++)if(!(-1>=a+c||this.moduleCount<=a+c))for(var d=-1;7>=d;d++)-1>=b+d||this.moduleCount<=b+d||(this.modules[a+c][b+d]=c>=0&&6>=c&&(0==d||6==d)||d>=0&&6>=d&&(0==c||6==c)||c>=2&&4>=c&&d>=2&&4>=d?!0:!1)},getBestMaskPattern:function(){for(var a=0,b=0,c=0;8>c;c++){this.makeImpl(!0,c);var d=f.getLostPoint(this);(0==c||a>d)&&(a=d,b=c)}return b},createMovieClip:function(a,b,c){var d=a.createEmptyMovieClip(b,c),e=1;this.make();for(var f=0;f<this.modules.length;f++)for(var g=f*e,h=0;h<this.modules[f].length;h++){var i=h*e,j=this.modules[f][h];j&&(d.beginFill(0,100),d.moveTo(i,g),d.lineTo(i+e,g),d.lineTo(i+e,g+e),d.lineTo(i,g+e),d.endFill())}return d},setupTimingPattern:function(){for(var a=8;a<this.moduleCount-8;a++)null==this.modules[a][6]&&(this.modules[a][6]=0==a%2);for(var b=8;b<this.moduleCount-8;b++)null==this.modules[6][b]&&(this.modules[6][b]=0==b%2)},setupPositionAdjustPattern:function(){for(var a=f.getPatternPosition(this.typeNumber),b=0;b<a.length;b++)for(var c=0;c<a.length;c++){var d=a[b],e=a[c];if(null==this.modules[d][e])for(var g=-2;2>=g;g++)for(var h=-2;2>=h;h++)this.modules[d+g][e+h]=-2==g||2==g||-2==h||2==h||0==g&&0==h?!0:!1}},setupTypeNumber:function(a){for(var b=f.getBCHTypeNumber(this.typeNumber),c=0;18>c;c++){var d=!a&&1==(1&b>>c);this.modules[Math.floor(c/3)][c%3+this.moduleCount-8-3]=d}for(var c=0;18>c;c++){var d=!a&&1==(1&b>>c);this.modules[c%3+this.moduleCount-8-3][Math.floor(c/3)]=d}},setupTypeInfo:function(a,b){for(var c=this.errorCorrectLevel<<3|b,d=f.getBCHTypeInfo(c),e=0;15>e;e++){var g=!a&&1==(1&d>>e);6>e?this.modules[e][8]=g:8>e?this.modules[e+1][8]=g:this.modules[this.moduleCount-15+e][8]=g}for(var e=0;15>e;e++){var g=!a&&1==(1&d>>e);8>e?this.modules[8][this.moduleCount-e-1]=g:9>e?this.modules[8][15-e-1+1]=g:this.modules[8][15-e-1]=g}this.modules[this.moduleCount-8][8]=!a},mapData:function(a,b){for(var c=-1,d=this.moduleCount-1,e=7,g=0,h=this.moduleCount-1;h>0;h-=2)for(6==h&&h--;;){for(var i=0;2>i;i++)if(null==this.modules[d][h-i]){var j=!1;g<a.length&&(j=1==(1&a[g]>>>e));var k=f.getMask(b,d,h-i);k&&(j=!j),this.modules[d][h-i]=j,e--,-1==e&&(g++,e=7)}if(d+=c,0>d||this.moduleCount<=d){d-=c,c=-c;break}}}},b.PAD0=236,b.PAD1=17,b.createData=function(a,c,d){for(var e=j.getRSBlocks(a,c),g=new k,h=0;h<d.length;h++){var i=d[h];g.put(i.mode,4),g.put(i.getLength(),f.getLengthInBits(i.mode,a)),i.write(g)}for(var l=0,h=0;h<e.length;h++)l+=e[h].dataCount;if(g.getLengthInBits()>8*l)throw new Error("code length overflow. ("+g.getLengthInBits()+">"+8*l+")");for(g.getLengthInBits()+4<=8*l&&g.put(0,4);0!=g.getLengthInBits()%8;)g.putBit(!1);for(;;){if(g.getLengthInBits()>=8*l)break;if(g.put(b.PAD0,8),g.getLengthInBits()>=8*l)break;g.put(b.PAD1,8)}return b.createBytes(g,e)},b.createBytes=function(a,b){for(var c=0,d=0,e=0,g=new Array(b.length),h=new Array(b.length),j=0;j<b.length;j++){var k=b[j].dataCount,l=b[j].totalCount-k;d=Math.max(d,k),e=Math.max(e,l),g[j]=new Array(k);for(var m=0;m<g[j].length;m++)g[j][m]=255&a.buffer[m+c];c+=k;var n=f.getErrorCorrectPolynomial(l),o=new i(g[j],n.getLength()-1),p=o.mod(n);h[j]=new Array(n.getLength()-1);for(var m=0;m<h[j].length;m++){var q=m+p.getLength()-h[j].length;h[j][m]=q>=0?p.get(q):0}}for(var r=0,m=0;m<b.length;m++)r+=b[m].totalCount;for(var s=new Array(r),t=0,m=0;d>m;m++)for(var j=0;j<b.length;j++)m<g[j].length&&(s[t++]=g[j][m]);for(var m=0;e>m;m++)for(var j=0;j<b.length;j++)m<h[j].length&&(s[t++]=h[j][m]);return s};for(var c={MODE_NUMBER:1,MODE_ALPHA_NUM:2,MODE_8BIT_BYTE:4,MODE_KANJI:8},d={L:1,M:0,Q:3,H:2},e={PATTERN000:0,PATTERN001:1,PATTERN010:2,PATTERN011:3,PATTERN100:4,PATTERN101:5,PATTERN110:6,PATTERN111:7},f={PATTERN_POSITION_TABLE:[[],[6,18],[6,22],[6,26],[6,30],[6,34],[6,22,38],[6,24,42],[6,26,46],[6,28,50],[6,30,54],[6,32,58],[6,34,62],[6,26,46,66],[6,26,48,70],[6,26,50,74],[6,30,54,78],[6,30,56,82],[6,30,58,86],[6,34,62,90],[6,28,50,72,94],[6,26,50,74,98],[6,30,54,78,102],[6,28,54,80,106],[6,32,58,84,110],[6,30,58,86,114],[6,34,62,90,118],[6,26,50,74,98,122],[6,30,54,78,102,126],[6,26,52,78,104,130],[6,30,56,82,108,134],[6,34,60,86,112,138],[6,30,58,86,114,142],[6,34,62,90,118,146],[6,30,54,78,102,126,150],[6,24,50,76,102,128,154],[6,28,54,80,106,132,158],[6,32,58,84,110,136,162],[6,26,54,82,110,138,166],[6,30,58,86,114,142,170]],G15:1335,G18:7973,G15_MASK:21522,getBCHTypeInfo:function(a){for(var b=a<<10;f.getBCHDigit(b)-f.getBCHDigit(f.G15)>=0;)b^=f.G15<<f.getBCHDigit(b)-f.getBCHDigit(f.G15);return(a<<10|b)^f.G15_MASK},getBCHTypeNumber:function(a){for(var b=a<<12;f.getBCHDigit(b)-f.getBCHDigit(f.G18)>=0;)b^=f.G18<<f.getBCHDigit(b)-f.getBCHDigit(f.G18);return a<<12|b},getBCHDigit:function(a){for(var b=0;0!=a;)b++,a>>>=1;return b},getPatternPosition:function(a){return f.PATTERN_POSITION_TABLE[a-1]},getMask:function(a,b,c){switch(a){case e.PATTERN000:return 0==(b+c)%2;case e.PATTERN001:return 0==b%2;case e.PATTERN010:return 0==c%3;case e.PATTERN011:return 0==(b+c)%3;case e.PATTERN100:return 0==(Math.floor(b/2)+Math.floor(c/3))%2;case e.PATTERN101:return 0==b*c%2+b*c%3;case e.PATTERN110:return 0==(b*c%2+b*c%3)%2;case e.PATTERN111:return 0==(b*c%3+(b+c)%2)%2;default:throw new Error("bad maskPattern:"+a)}},getErrorCorrectPolynomial:function(a){for(var b=new i([1],0),c=0;a>c;c++)b=b.multiply(new i([1,g.gexp(c)],0));return b},getLengthInBits:function(a,b){if(b>=1&&10>b)switch(a){case c.MODE_NUMBER:return 10;case c.MODE_ALPHA_NUM:return 9;case c.MODE_8BIT_BYTE:return 8;case c.MODE_KANJI:return 8;default:throw new Error("mode:"+a)}else if(27>b)switch(a){case c.MODE_NUMBER:return 12;case c.MODE_ALPHA_NUM:return 11;case c.MODE_8BIT_BYTE:return 16;case c.MODE_KANJI:return 10;default:throw new Error("mode:"+a)}else{if(!(41>b))throw new Error("type:"+b);switch(a){case c.MODE_NUMBER:return 14;case c.MODE_ALPHA_NUM:return 13;case c.MODE_8BIT_BYTE:return 16;case c.MODE_KANJI:return 12;default:throw new Error("mode:"+a)}}},getLostPoint:function(a){for(var b=a.getModuleCount(),c=0,d=0;b>d;d++)for(var e=0;b>e;e++){for(var f=0,g=a.isDark(d,e),h=-1;1>=h;h++)if(!(0>d+h||d+h>=b))for(var i=-1;1>=i;i++)0>e+i||e+i>=b||(0!=h||0!=i)&&g==a.isDark(d+h,e+i)&&f++;f>5&&(c+=3+f-5)}for(var d=0;b-1>d;d++)for(var e=0;b-1>e;e++){var j=0;a.isDark(d,e)&&j++,a.isDark(d+1,e)&&j++,a.isDark(d,e+1)&&j++,a.isDark(d+1,e+1)&&j++,(0==j||4==j)&&(c+=3)}for(var d=0;b>d;d++)for(var e=0;b-6>e;e++)a.isDark(d,e)&&!a.isDark(d,e+1)&&a.isDark(d,e+2)&&a.isDark(d,e+3)&&a.isDark(d,e+4)&&!a.isDark(d,e+5)&&a.isDark(d,e+6)&&(c+=40);for(var e=0;b>e;e++)for(var d=0;b-6>d;d++)a.isDark(d,e)&&!a.isDark(d+1,e)&&a.isDark(d+2,e)&&a.isDark(d+3,e)&&a.isDark(d+4,e)&&!a.isDark(d+5,e)&&a.isDark(d+6,e)&&(c+=40);for(var k=0,e=0;b>e;e++)for(var d=0;b>d;d++)a.isDark(d,e)&&k++;var l=Math.abs(100*k/b/b-50)/5;return c+=10*l}},g={glog:function(a){if(1>a)throw new Error("glog("+a+")");return g.LOG_TABLE[a]},gexp:function(a){for(;0>a;)a+=255;for(;a>=256;)a-=255;return g.EXP_TABLE[a]},EXP_TABLE:new Array(256),LOG_TABLE:new Array(256)},h=0;8>h;h++)g.EXP_TABLE[h]=1<<h;for(var h=8;256>h;h++)g.EXP_TABLE[h]=g.EXP_TABLE[h-4]^g.EXP_TABLE[h-5]^g.EXP_TABLE[h-6]^g.EXP_TABLE[h-8];for(var h=0;255>h;h++)g.LOG_TABLE[g.EXP_TABLE[h]]=h;i.prototype={get:function(a){return this.num[a]},getLength:function(){return this.num.length},multiply:function(a){for(var b=new Array(this.getLength()+a.getLength()-1),c=0;c<this.getLength();c++)for(var d=0;d<a.getLength();d++)b[c+d]^=g.gexp(g.glog(this.get(c))+g.glog(a.get(d)));return new i(b,0)},mod:function(a){if(this.getLength()-a.getLength()<0)return this;for(var b=g.glog(this.get(0))-g.glog(a.get(0)),c=new Array(this.getLength()),d=0;d<this.getLength();d++)c[d]=this.get(d);for(var d=0;d<a.getLength();d++)c[d]^=g.gexp(g.glog(a.get(d))+b);return new i(c,0).mod(a)}},j.RS_BLOCK_TABLE=[[1,26,19],[1,26,16],[1,26,13],[1,26,9],[1,44,34],[1,44,28],[1,44,22],[1,44,16],[1,70,55],[1,70,44],[2,35,17],[2,35,13],[1,100,80],[2,50,32],[2,50,24],[4,25,9],[1,134,108],[2,67,43],[2,33,15,2,34,16],[2,33,11,2,34,12],[2,86,68],[4,43,27],[4,43,19],[4,43,15],[2,98,78],[4,49,31],[2,32,14,4,33,15],[4,39,13,1,40,14],[2,121,97],[2,60,38,2,61,39],[4,40,18,2,41,19],[4,40,14,2,41,15],[2,146,116],[3,58,36,2,59,37],[4,36,16,4,37,17],[4,36,12,4,37,13],[2,86,68,2,87,69],[4,69,43,1,70,44],[6,43,19,2,44,20],[6,43,15,2,44,16],[4,101,81],[1,80,50,4,81,51],[4,50,22,4,51,23],[3,36,12,8,37,13],[2,116,92,2,117,93],[6,58,36,2,59,37],[4,46,20,6,47,21],[7,42,14,4,43,15],[4,133,107],[8,59,37,1,60,38],[8,44,20,4,45,21],[12,33,11,4,34,12],[3,145,115,1,146,116],[4,64,40,5,65,41],[11,36,16,5,37,17],[11,36,12,5,37,13],[5,109,87,1,110,88],[5,65,41,5,66,42],[5,54,24,7,55,25],[11,36,12],[5,122,98,1,123,99],[7,73,45,3,74,46],[15,43,19,2,44,20],[3,45,15,13,46,16],[1,135,107,5,136,108],[10,74,46,1,75,47],[1,50,22,15,51,23],[2,42,14,17,43,15],[5,150,120,1,151,121],[9,69,43,4,70,44],[17,50,22,1,51,23],[2,42,14,19,43,15],[3,141,113,4,142,114],[3,70,44,11,71,45],[17,47,21,4,48,22],[9,39,13,16,40,14],[3,135,107,5,136,108],[3,67,41,13,68,42],[15,54,24,5,55,25],[15,43,15,10,44,16],[4,144,116,4,145,117],[17,68,42],[17,50,22,6,51,23],[19,46,16,6,47,17],[2,139,111,7,140,112],[17,74,46],[7,54,24,16,55,25],[34,37,13],[4,151,121,5,152,122],[4,75,47,14,76,48],[11,54,24,14,55,25],[16,45,15,14,46,16],[6,147,117,4,148,118],[6,73,45,14,74,46],[11,54,24,16,55,25],[30,46,16,2,47,17],[8,132,106,4,133,107],[8,75,47,13,76,48],[7,54,24,22,55,25],[22,45,15,13,46,16],[10,142,114,2,143,115],[19,74,46,4,75,47],[28,50,22,6,51,23],[33,46,16,4,47,17],[8,152,122,4,153,123],[22,73,45,3,74,46],[8,53,23,26,54,24],[12,45,15,28,46,16],[3,147,117,10,148,118],[3,73,45,23,74,46],[4,54,24,31,55,25],[11,45,15,31,46,16],[7,146,116,7,147,117],[21,73,45,7,74,46],[1,53,23,37,54,24],[19,45,15,26,46,16],[5,145,115,10,146,116],[19,75,47,10,76,48],[15,54,24,25,55,25],[23,45,15,25,46,16],[13,145,115,3,146,116],[2,74,46,29,75,47],[42,54,24,1,55,25],[23,45,15,28,46,16],[17,145,115],[10,74,46,23,75,47],[10,54,24,35,55,25],[19,45,15,35,46,16],[17,145,115,1,146,116],[14,74,46,21,75,47],[29,54,24,19,55,25],[11,45,15,46,46,16],[13,145,115,6,146,116],[14,74,46,23,75,47],[44,54,24,7,55,25],[59,46,16,1,47,17],[12,151,121,7,152,122],[12,75,47,26,76,48],[39,54,24,14,55,25],[22,45,15,41,46,16],[6,151,121,14,152,122],[6,75,47,34,76,48],[46,54,24,10,55,25],[2,45,15,64,46,16],[17,152,122,4,153,123],[29,74,46,14,75,47],[49,54,24,10,55,25],[24,45,15,46,46,16],[4,152,122,18,153,123],[13,74,46,32,75,47],[48,54,24,14,55,25],[42,45,15,32,46,16],[20,147,117,4,148,118],[40,75,47,7,76,48],[43,54,24,22,55,25],[10,45,15,67,46,16],[19,148,118,6,149,119],[18,75,47,31,76,48],[34,54,24,34,55,25],[20,45,15,61,46,16]],j.getRSBlocks=function(a,b){var c=j.getRsBlockTable(a,b);if(void 0==c)throw new Error("bad rs block @ typeNumber:"+a+"/errorCorrectLevel:"+b);for(var d=c.length/3,e=[],f=0;d>f;f++)for(var g=c[3*f+0],h=c[3*f+1],i=c[3*f+2],k=0;g>k;k++)e.push(new j(h,i));return e},j.getRsBlockTable=function(a,b){switch(b){case d.L:return j.RS_BLOCK_TABLE[4*(a-1)+0];case d.M:return j.RS_BLOCK_TABLE[4*(a-1)+1];case d.Q:return j.RS_BLOCK_TABLE[4*(a-1)+2];case d.H:return j.RS_BLOCK_TABLE[4*(a-1)+3];default:return void 0}},k.prototype={get:function(a){var b=Math.floor(a/8);return 1==(1&this.buffer[b]>>>7-a%8)},put:function(a,b){for(var c=0;b>c;c++)this.putBit(1==(1&a>>>b-c-1))},getLengthInBits:function(){return this.length},putBit:function(a){var b=Math.floor(this.length/8);this.buffer.length<=b&&this.buffer.push(0),a&&(this.buffer[b]|=128>>>this.length%8),this.length++}};var l=[[17,14,11,7],[32,26,20,14],[53,42,32,24],[78,62,46,34],[106,84,60,44],[134,106,74,58],[154,122,86,64],[192,152,108,84],[230,180,130,98],[271,213,151,119],[321,251,177,137],[367,287,203,155],[425,331,241,177],[458,362,258,194],[520,412,292,220],[586,450,322,250],[644,504,364,280],[718,560,394,310],[792,624,442,338],[858,666,482,382],[929,711,509,403],[1003,779,565,439],[1091,857,611,461],[1171,911,661,511],[1273,997,715,535],[1367,1059,751,593],[1465,1125,805,625],[1528,1190,868,658],[1628,1264,908,698],[1732,1370,982,742],[1840,1452,1030,790],[1952,1538,1112,842],[2068,1628,1168,898],[2188,1722,1228,958],[2303,1809,1283,983],[2431,1911,1351,1051],[2563,1989,1423,1093],[2699,2099,1499,1139],[2809,2213,1579,1219],[2953,2331,1663,1273]],o=function(){var a=function(a,b){this._el=a,this._htOption=b};return a.prototype.draw=function(a){function g(a,b){var c=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",a);for(var d in b)b.hasOwnProperty(d)&&c.setAttribute(d,b[d]);return c}var b=this._htOption,c=this._el,d=a.getModuleCount();Math.floor(b.width/d),Math.floor(b.height/d),this.clear();var h=g("svg",{viewBox:"0 0 "+String(d)+" "+String(d),width:"100%",height:"100%",fill:b.colorLight});h.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:xlink","http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"),c.appendChild(h),h.appendChild(g("rect",{fill:b.colorDark,width:"1",height:"1",id:"template"}));for(var i=0;d>i;i++)for(var j=0;d>j;j++)if(a.isDark(i,j)){var k=g("use",{x:String(i),y:String(j)});k.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink","href","#template"),h.appendChild(k)}},a.prototype.clear=function(){for(;this._el.hasChildNodes();)this._el.removeChild(this._el.lastChild)},a}(),p="svg"===document.documentElement.tagName.toLowerCase(),q=p?o:m()?function(){function a(){this._elImage.src=this._elCanvas.toDataURL("image/png"),this._elImage.style.display="block",this._elCanvas.style.display="none"}function d(a,b){var c=this;if(c._fFail=b,c._fSuccess=a,null===c._bSupportDataURI){var d=document.createElement("img"),e=function(){c._bSupportDataURI=!1,c._fFail&&_fFail.call(c)},f=function(){c._bSupportDataURI=!0,c._fSuccess&&c._fSuccess.call(c)};return d.onabort=e,d.onerror=e,d.onload=f,d.src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",void 0}c._bSupportDataURI===!0&&c._fSuccess?c._fSuccess.call(c):c._bSupportDataURI===!1&&c._fFail&&c._fFail.call(c)}if(this._android&&this._android<=2.1){var b=1/window.devicePixelRatio,c=CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImage;CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImage=function(a,d,e,f,g,h,i,j){if("nodeName"in a&&/img/i.test(a.nodeName))for(var l=arguments.length-1;l>=1;l--)arguments[l]=arguments[l]*b;else"undefined"==typeof j&&(arguments[1]*=b,arguments[2]*=b,arguments[3]*=b,arguments[4]*=b);c.apply(this,arguments)}}var e=function(a,b){this._bIsPainted=!1,this._android=n(),this._htOption=b,this._elCanvas=document.createElement("canvas"),this._elCanvas.width=b.width,this._elCanvas.height=b.height,a.appendChild(this._elCanvas),this._el=a,this._oContext=this._elCanvas.getContext("2d"),this._bIsPainted=!1,this._elImage=document.createElement("img"),this._elImage.style.display="none",this._el.appendChild(this._elImage),this._bSupportDataURI=null};return e.prototype.draw=function(a){var b=this._elImage,c=this._oContext,d=this._htOption,e=a.getModuleCount(),f=d.width/e,g=d.height/e,h=Math.round(f),i=Math.round(g);b.style.display="none",this.clear();for(var j=0;e>j;j++)for(var k=0;e>k;k++){var l=a.isDark(j,k),m=k*f,n=j*g;c.strokeStyle=l?d.colorDark:d.colorLight,c.lineWidth=1,c.fillStyle=l?d.colorDark:d.colorLight,c.fillRect(m,n,f,g),c.strokeRect(Math.floor(m)+.5,Math.floor(n)+.5,h,i),c.strokeRect(Math.ceil(m)-.5,Math.ceil(n)-.5,h,i)}this._bIsPainted=!0},e.prototype.makeImage=function(){this._bIsPainted&&d.call(this,a)},e.prototype.isPainted=function(){return this._bIsPainted},e.prototype.clear=function(){this._oContext.clearRect(0,0,this._elCanvas.width,this._elCanvas.height),this._bIsPainted=!1},e.prototype.round=function(a){return a?Math.floor(1e3*a)/1e3:a},e}():function(){var a=function(a,b){this._el=a,this._htOption=b};return a.prototype.draw=function(a){for(var b=this._htOption,c=this._el,d=a.getModuleCount(),e=Math.floor(b.width/d),f=Math.floor(b.height/d),g=['<table style="border:0;border-collapse:collapse;">'],h=0;d>h;h++){g.push("<tr>");for(var i=0;d>i;i++)g.push('<td style="border:0;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;margin:0;width:'+e+"px;height:"+f+"px;background-color:"+(a.isDark(h,i)?b.colorDark:b.colorLight)+';"></td>');g.push("</tr>")}g.push("</table>"),c.innerHTML=g.join("");var j=c.childNodes[0],k=(b.width-j.offsetWidth)/2,l=(b.height-j.offsetHeight)/2;k>0&&l>0&&(j.style.margin=l+"px "+k+"px")},a.prototype.clear=function(){this._el.innerHTML=""},a}();QRCode=function(a,b){if(this._htOption={width:256,height:256,typeNumber:4,colorDark:"#000000",colorLight:"#ffffff",correctLevel:d.H},"string"==typeof b&&(b={text:b}),b)for(var c in b)this._htOption[c]=b[c];"string"==typeof a&&(a=document.getElementById(a)),this._android=n(),this._el=a,this._oQRCode=null,this._oDrawing=new q(this._el,this._htOption),this._htOption.text&&this.makeCode(this._htOption.text)},QRCode.prototype.makeCode=function(a){this._oQRCode=new b(r(a,this._htOption.correctLevel),this._htOption.correctLevel),this._oQRCode.addData(a),this._oQRCode.make(),this._el.title=a,this._oDrawing.draw(this._oQRCode),this.makeImage()},QRCode.prototype.makeImage=function(){"function"==typeof this._oDrawing.makeImage&&(!this._android||this._android>=3)&&this._oDrawing.makeImage()},QRCode.prototype.clear=function(){this._oDrawing.clear()},QRCode.CorrectLevel=d}();

var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    });

qrcode.makeCode("Hello World");
console.log(document.getElementById("qrcode").innerHTML)
```